# jQuery flicker on click?

Tags: jquery

Is there any type of jQuery or JavaScript functionality that would enable me to:

```
$('#button').click(function() {
  //flicker ('#element');
}
```

I want it to flicker when the button is clicked.  Is this possible?

Comment: By flicker do you mean quickly remove and replace? Or change background to white and back? What do you mean?

Comment: Like a flicker.  I don't know how to explain it any better.

Comment: Have you looked at jquery-ui effects?

Answer (score 0):

How about the jquery ui effects plugin using pulsate

see http://jqueryui.com/effect/

Answer (score 0):

In the jQuery UI section you have a list of `effect()`

[JQUERY UI](http://jqueryui.com/effect/)

In the list box where it shows 'Blind' change to 'Shake'

For you to use it, you just have to install jquery-ui in your project.

[JQUERY UI DOWNLOAD](http://jqueryui.com/)